# Gradle fails to resolve dependencies from bintray

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, bintray

I have uploaded library to bintray, but when I try to use it in my project gradle build fails with Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.ymirski.library:date-utils:0.0.1

Here is my app build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.ymirski.library:date-utils:0.0.1'
}
```

project build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url  "http://droidlab.bintray.com/maven"
        }
    }
}
```

all data I've got from bintray:
[image]

[image]

Comment: This means there is no such library in bintray.

Comment: but i got this links from bintray

Comment: please link to jcenter and use

Comment: Then clean your project and run again.

Comment: I'm linking library with jcenter but it takes several hours. Clean project doesn't help

Comment: I sucessfully added your library to my test project.

Comment: Thank you for reply. This is strange, but I can use library only after it is linked to jcenter, but I can't when it doesn't

Answer (score 3):

The URL that worked for me is:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven {
            url  "https://dl.bintray.com/your-bintray-username/maven"
        }
    }
}
```

Add this in your project-level build.gradle file. Also replace 'your-bintray-username' with your Bintray username in the URL.

Now in your app-level build.gradle compile your library as:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'your.group.id:your.artifact.id:version'
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't publish your library correctly. If you specify the dependency in Gradle like you did, it expects to find a JAR file, not an AAR file. If Gradle supports depending on AAR files (I don't do Android development), you probably have to explicitly state that you want the AAR by using `compile 'com.ymirski.library:date-utils:0.0.1@aar'`. But even with that, it does not work, which makes me think that you didn't do the publishing on Bintray correctly. But as I'm also not familiar with Bintray, I cannot tell you what is wrong exactly.